# How to calculate percentage in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query of 4 columns

- directorate,
- t1 for number of the employees under the directorate who took the courses
- t2 for number of the courses that the directorate took
- t3 for the total prize that spend of each directorate

I want to add `t4` for the percentage of the total prize of every directorate

The formula is `(t3 / total sum of t3) * 100`

This is the query:

```
with cte1 as
(
    select   
        vwemployee.directorateName, 
        count(distinct vwemployeeCourse.employeeId) as t1 
    from 
        vwemployee, vwemployeeCourse 
    where  
        vwemployee.directorateName = vwemployeeCourse.directorateName 
    group by    
       vwemployee.directorateName
), cte2 as
(
    select 
        vwemployee.directorateName, 
        count(vwemployee.directorateName) as t2 
    from 
        vwemployee, employeeCourse
    where 
        vwemployee.Id = employeeCourse.employeeId 
    group by 
        vwemployee.directorateName
), cte3 as
(
    select 
        vwemployeeCourse.directorateName, 
        sum(vwCourse.cost) as t3
    from 
        vwemployeeCourse, vwCourse
    where 
        vwemployeeCourse.courseId = vwCourse.Id
    group by
        vwemployeeCourse.directorateName 
)
select 
    cte1.directorateName, cte1.t1, cte2.t2, cte3.t3
from
    cte1 
inner join 
    cte2 on cte1.directorateName = cte2.directorateName
inner join 
    cte3 on cte2.directorateName = cte3.directorateName
```

So far I have learned how to combine queries together, but I want to learn how to use operation like above.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: every time i use join i get the wrong output but you feel free to redesign the query if you can and show me how because i am a week old SQL beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window fucntions:

```
with . . .
select cte1.directorateName, cte1.t1, cte2.t2, cte3.t3,
       cte3.t3 / sum(cte3.t3) over ()
from cte1 inner join
     cte2 
     on cte1.directorateName = cte2.directorateName inner join
     cte3
     on cte2.directorateName = cte3.directorateName;
```

If `t3` is an integer, then you need to convert it to a number with a decimal point (SQL Server does integer division):

```
with . . .
select cte1.directorateName, cte1.t1, cte2.t2, cte3.t3,
       cte3.t3*100.0 / sum(cte3.t3) over ()
from cte1 inner join
     cte2 
     on cte1.directorateName = cte2.directorateName inner join
     cte3
     on cte2.directorateName = cte3.directorateName;
```

Comment: yeah the second query works but you forgot to multiply it by 100 but i did add it thank you <3